# Gradle doesn't recognize mainModule properly

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a simple javaFx project. I decided to create a module-info to require javaFX libraries for my project. Before that my program worked fine but now
`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resPath)` can't get a resource from my resources. Also I get this message every time when I run my application:

**No module was provided for main class, assuming the current module. Prefer providing 'mainClassName' in the following format: '$moduleName/a.b.Main'**

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

version '1.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).configureEach {
    java {
        modularity.inferModulePath = true
    }
}


tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'liug'
    mainClass = 'render.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

And module-info:

```
module moduleInfo {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;


    opens controller to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    opens core to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    opens popups to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    opens render to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    opens stages to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    opens view to javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;

    exports controller;
    exports core;
    exports popups;
    exports render;
    exports stages;
    exports view;
    exports core.buildings;
}
```

> [here is my projects structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTMwF.png)

Can somebody say what I do wrong?

Comment: The [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) also applies the [gradle-modules-plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin) which may not be compatible with the new module features Gradle added in 6.4. You may want to consider submitting issues to either or both if they haven't already worked on the problem for newer versions.

Comment: I have found out that javaFX provides an opportunity to make modular JavaFX project via gradle (https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij). I replaced `application{..}` with `mainClassName = "$moduleName/Main"` in build.gradle in accordance with instruction. Now idea throws: Error: **Could not find or load main class Main in module render**
Any ideas?

Comment: It's `module/main-class`, meaning I believe it should be `liug/render.Main` in your case.

Comment: When the problem is:
**Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package liug.render not found in module**

Comment: I have changed module-info name for several times and found out that this snippet:
`mainClassName = "$moduleName/Main"` finds a package with the same name a module-info name. For example if I set projectCityBuilder as a name for module-info my program will throw:
`Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package projectCityBuilder not found in module`

Comment: Version 0.0.9 of javafx-gradle-plugin has just been published, solves many of the above mentioned issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in project structure and like it was said in gradle version. I wrote this snippet: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip` in gradle-wrapper.properties and changed the name of package with fxml resources ([how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Cxu.png)). Also I changed path to the resource which I had used to get an FXML file. That is how it looks like now:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("MaiMenu.fxml");
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
```

[This tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) helped me really well.
I still have some problems but I think they are not connected with this question so I am closing it.